# update word1 to be the last word generated

Tags: python

(In Python)
Using a bigram dictionary built from Green Eggs and Ham.

I would like to ask the user for a word(word1) which is in a *bigram dictionary/list*. In the first loop the users input(Word1) will print out a random value from it's list in the dictionary (word2), for every loop after that will update so word2 become the last word we generated.

In short, Ask user for starting word then print it a newly generated pair of words 5 times.

Here's an example of what the output should do:

```
input: do
do not
not like
like green
green eggs
eggs and
```

Here is my code so far.

```
import random
bigrams = {'Do': ['you'], 'you': ['like', 'like', 'like', 'like'], 'like': ['green', 
'them,', 'green', 'them', 'them', 'them', 'green', 'them,', 'them', 'them', 'them', 'them', 
'them', 'them', 'green', 'them,'], 'green': ['eggs', 'eggs', 'eggs', 'eggs'], 'eggs': 
['and', 'and', 'and', 'and'], 'and': ['ham?', 'ham.', 'ham.', 'ham.'], 'ham?': ['I'], 'I': 
['do', 'am.', 'do', 'would', 'would', 'do', 'do', 'am.', 'do', 'do', 'do', 'do', 'do', 'do', 
'am.'], 'do': ['not', 'not', 'not', 'not', 'not', 'not', 'not', 'not', 'not', 'not'], 'not': 
['like', 'like', 'like', 'like', 'like', 'like', 'like', 'like', 'like', 'like', 'like', 
'like'], 'them,': ['Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam'], 'Sam': ['I', 'I', 'I'], 'am.': ['I', 'Would'], 
'ham.': ['Would', 'I', 'I'], 'Would': ['you', 'you', 'you'], 'them': ['here', 'here', 
'anywhere.', 'in', 'with', 'in', 'with', 'here', 'anywhere.'], 'here': ['or', 'or', 'or'], 
'or': ['there?', 'there.', 'there.'], 'there?': ['I'], 'would': ['not', 'not'], 'there.': 
['I', 'I'], 'anywhere.': ['I', 'I'], 'in': ['a', 'a'], 'a': ['house?', 'mouse?', 'house.', 
'mouse.'], 'house?': ['Would'], 'with': ['a', 'a'], 'mouse?': ['I'], 'house.': ['I'], 
'mouse.': ['I']}

word = input('Word: ')
for i in range(5):
  word = random.choice(bigrams[word])
  print(word, random.choice(bigrams[word]))
```

and this is the current output.

```
Word: do
not like
like them
them here
here or
or there.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're resetting the value of `word`. Try:

```
for i in range(5):
  next_word = random.choice(bigrams[word])
  print(word, next_word)
  word = next_word
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to programming and i am still learning the ropes.